# RequestBody and Validation Annotation are null

Tags: validation, spring5

I made a method in RestController. this method takes json objects, and enters it into the database and returns the status.

```
@PostMapping("/api/members")
    public void newMember(
            @RequestBody @Valid RegisterRequest regReq, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
                try {
                    Long newMemberId = registerService.regist(regReq);  //putting database
                    response.setHeader("Location", "/api/members/" + newMemberId); 
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED); 
                } catch (DuplicateMemberException dupEx){ 
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT); 
                }
            }
```

It performs a good job putting it into the database.

However, as I checked with the Advance REST client program, the status was `201 supported media type`,  not `201 created`.

At the console window, there is an error as below.

```
00:00:10.444 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils - Failed to meta-introspect annotation [interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotation must not be null
00:00:10.444 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils - Failed to meta-introspect annotation [interface javax.validation.Valid]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotation must not be null
```

RequestBody and Validation are null and cannot be used properly.

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
```

When importing, there was no error, no red line on this line. What should I do?

Below is pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sp5</groupId>
<artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2-b02</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>8.5.61</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
<version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
<encoding>utf-8</encoding>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```